# How do i print Hello World using Gitlab CI .yml file

Tags: c, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to print Hello World using message C language from gitlab ci. But I am not getting the message my pipeline builds successfully. Below is the .yml code:

```
image: gcc

build: 
    stage: build


    script: 
        - gcc src/c-test.c -o mybinary
    artifacts:
        paths:
            - mybinary
    cache:
        paths: 
            - "*.o"
```

The pipeline builds perfectly but I am not seeing the message I wrote in printf. All I am seeing the message that the Job succeeded.

Comment: What about running the resulting executable?

Comment: You're not running the excutable, what do you expect? Add `- ./mybinary` to the `script:` section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to execute the resulting binary.
Add `- ./mybinary` to the `script:` section, like this:

```
image: gcc

build: 
    stage: build


    script: 
        - gcc src/c-test.c -o mybinary
        - ./mybinary # here
    artifacts:
        paths:
            - mybinary
    cache:
        paths: 
            - "*.o"
```